# Error while building React-Native application

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, expo

How the issue appeared ?

1 - I started a new blank react-native project using `react-native init projectName`

2 - I moved screens and components from exiting project to the new one

3 - I installed the required npm modules that's I use inside the project (including expo) `npm install --save expo`

that's the error which I got "check the below image" , however I installed expo

that's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "taplot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^29.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-icon-badge": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-public-ip": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-toaster": "^1.2.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @AravindS MAC OS

Comment: so - no one has answer -_-

Comment: I faced issues with RN .56 and window 10. You can find the details here, which is still open https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953

Comment: @AravindS , someone advised me to downgrade RN to .54

Comment: Downgrading to 55 will also work

Comment: So - did you try to downgrade and worked with you - I downgraded to 54 but did not work - `npm install react-native@0.55.4 --save`

Comment: @AravindS downgrading to 55 - worked with you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177037/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-27mdmo7sn).

Comment: yes it worked for me.. npm install react-native@0.55.0 and Check the installed version react-native -version

Comment: Good = my project totally damaged

Comment: What do you mean..by downgrading ?

Comment: uninstalling react-native then install it again using `npm install react-native@0.55.4 --save`

Comment: @AravindS , now I'm facing this unknown error : https://scontent-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/38139435_1609386985834350_5247904514735865856_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=9fa250dfb9f71d640491a4ef9da98cfc&oe=5BCE1350